# Is there another Ruby library for making a simple HTTP Proxy besides WEBrick?

Tags: ruby, http, proxy

WEBrick as the `HTTPProxyServer` class that makes it easy to set up a simple HTTP proxy server. But I've been running into some issues with this library. Are there any other Ruby alternatives that are equally easy to set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [EM-Proxy](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-proxy).  I haven't worked with it, but from the docs it certainly looks like a simple solution.  In fact, there is an [example script](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-proxy/blob/master/examples/http_proxy.rb) in the repo.